# What to do when a div is not expanding to fit it's content, and clear-fixes don't work?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I'm creating "virtual business cards" that give you a brief profile on a person. When you click on them, they rotate and give you a more in depth profile on the "back" of the card.

The problem is that I can't get the cards to expand (height wise) to fit their content. I've tried every "clear fix" I could find and nothing has worked so far. I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kd7vwd2o/), check it out and you'll see exactly what I'm talking about.

How can I get the left-most card to fit it's content, and have the other two to match its' size?

(I'm trying to keep all the cards the same size by having them expand to the size of the largest card)

UPDATE: PROGRESS! I have found out that this is because the parent is positioned relatively, and the child is positioned absolutely.

HOWEVER, This is actually what puts the back and front of the card together. So If I position the children relatively, the div's expand to fit their content (HOORAY!) but the "back" of the card shows up below the "front" of the card. ([here](https://jsfiddle.net/kfja1L6o/) is a second fiddle to show you what I mean)

Any ideas on how to overcome this?

```
<style>

/* This styles the vCard container*/
.vCardContainer{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    perspective: 800px;
}   

/* This styles the vCard as a whole */
.vCard{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 1s;
}

/* Styles that apply to the front AND back of the vCard */
.vCard .vCardFront, 
.vCard .vCardBack{
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #939393;
}

/*Styles for the FRONT of the vCard*/
.vCard .vCardFront{
    border-top: 15px solid ;
}

/**
    Styles for the BACK of the vCard:
    (The back needs to start rotated)
*/
.vCard .vCardBack{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* This flips the entire vCard */
.vCard.flipped{
    transform:rotateY(180deg);

}
```

```
<div class="vCardContainer">
    <div class="vCard">
        <div class='vCardFront'>
            <h3 class="leadName">John Doe</h3>
            <p>Phone: 555-555-5555</p>
            <p>Email: john.doe@gmail.com</p>
            <p>Street: 555 Main Street</p>
            <p>Unit Number: 33</p>
            <p>City: New York</p>
            <p>State: NY</p>
            <p>Zip: 55555</p>
        </div>

        <div class='vCardBack hidden'>
            <h3 class="leadName">Info on John Doe</h3>
            <p>Sales:</p>
            <ul>
                <li class="tab">Naturals2Go</li>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab">Units Bought: 4</li>
                        <li class="tab"></li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="vCardContainer">
    <div class="vCard">
        <div class='vCardFront'>
            <h3 class="leadName">John Doe</h3>
            <p>Phone: 270-331-0169</p>
            <p>Email: john.doe@gmail.com</p>
        </div>

        <div class='vCardBack hidden'>
            <h3 class="leadName">Info on John Doe</h3>
            <p>Sales:</p>
            <ul>
                <li class="tab">Naturals2Go</li>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab">Units Bought: 4</li>
                        <li class="tab"></li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="vCardContainer">
    <div class="vCard">
        <div class='vCardFront'>
            <h3 class="leadName">John Doe</h3>
            <p>Phone: 270-331-0169</p>
            <p>Email: john.doe@gmail.com</p>
        </div>

        <div class='vCardBack hidden'>
            <h3 class="leadName">Info on John Doe</h3>
            <p>Sales:</p>
            <ul>
                <li class="tab">Naturals2Go</li>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab">Units Bought: 4</li>
                        <li class="tab"></li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="vCardContainer">
    <div class="vCard">
        <div class='vCardFront'>
            <h3 class="leadName">John Doe</h3>
            <p>Phone: 270-331-0169</p>
            <p>Email: john.doe@gmail.com</p>
        </div>

        <div class='vCardBack hidden'>
            <h3 class="leadName">Info on John Doe</h3>
            <p>Sales:</p>
            <ul>
                <li class="tab">Naturals2Go</li>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab">Units Bought: 4</li>
                        <li class="tab"></li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="vCardContainer">
    <div class="vCard">
        <div class='vCardFront'>
            <h3 class="leadName">John Doe</h3>
            <p>Phone: 270-331-0169</p>
            <p>Email: john.doe@gmail.com</p>
        </div>

        <div class='vCardBack hidden'>
            <h3 class="leadName">Info on John Doe</h3>
            <p>Sales:</p>
            <ul>
                <li class="tab">Naturals2Go</li>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab">Units Bought: 4</li>
                        <li class="tab"></li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
jQuery(".vCard").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("flipped");
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use some more code, you could try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() 
{
     var objHeight = 0;
     var list = [];
  $('.vCardFront').each(function(i, obj) {
    objHeight = 0;
    $(this).children().each(function(i, obj) {
    objHeight += $(this).height();
});
    list.push(objHeight);
});
  var large = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if(large < list[i]){
      large = list[i];
    }
}
     $('.vCardContainer').height(large * 2);
});
```

```css
document {
  display: none;
}
/* This styles the vCard container*/
.vCardContainer{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    /*min-height: 250px;*/
    position: relative;
    perspective: 800px;
}   

/* This styles the vCard as a whole */
.vCard{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 1s;
}

/* Styles that apply to the front AND back of the vCard */
.vCard .vCardFront, 
.vCard .vCardBack{
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #939393;
}

/*Styles for the FRONT of the vCard*/
.vCard .vCardFront{
    border-top: 15px solid ;
}

/**
    Styles for the BACK of the vCard:
    (The back needs to start rotated)
*/
.vCard .vCardBack{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* This flips the entire vCard */
.vCard.flipped{
    transform:rotateY(180deg);

}
```

```html
<div class="vCardContainer">
    <div class="vCard">
        <div class='vCardFront'>
            <h3 class="leadName">John Doe</h3>
            <p>Phone: 555-555-5555</p>
            <p>Email: john.doe@gmail.com</p>
            
        </div>

        <div class='vCardBack hidden'>
            <h3 class="leadName">Info on John Doe</h3>
            <p>Sales:</p>
            <ul>
                <li class="tab">Naturals2Go</li>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab">Units Bought: 4</li>
                        <li class="tab"></li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="vCardContainer">
    <div class="vCard">
        <div class='vCardFront'>
            <h3 class="leadName">John Doe</h3>
            <p>Phone: 270-331-0169</p>
            <p>Email: john.doe@gmail.com</p>
          <p>Street: 555 Main Street</p>
            <p>Unit Number: 33</p>
            <p>City: New York</p>
            <p>State: NY</p>
            <p>Zip: 55555</p>
        </div>

        <div class='vCardBack hidden'>
            <h3 class="leadName">Info on John Doe</h3>
            <p>Sales:</p>
            <ul>
                <li class="tab">Naturals2Go</li>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab">Units Bought: 4</li>
                        <li class="tab"></li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="vCardContainer">
    <div class="vCard">
        <div class='vCardFront'>
            <h3 class="leadName">John Doe</h3>
            <p>Phone: 270-331-0169</p>
            <p>Email: john.doe@gmail.com</p>

          
        </div>

        <div class='vCardBack hidden'>
            <h3 class="leadName">Info on John Doe</h3>
            <p>Sales:</p>
            <ul>
                <li class="tab">Naturals2Go</li>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab">Units Bought: 4</li>
                        <li class="tab">fsdfsdfsdfsdf</li>
                      <li class="tab">Units Bought: 4</li>
                        <li class="tab">fsdfsdfsdfsdf</li>
                      <li class="tab">Units Bought: 4</li>
                        <li class="tab">fsdfsdfsdfsdf</li>
                      <li class="tab">Units Bought: 4</li>
                        <li class="tab">fsdfsdfsdfsdf</li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="vCardContainer">
    <div class="vCard">
        <div class='vCardFront'>
            <h3 class="leadName">John Doe</h3>
            <p>Phone: 270-331-0169</p>
            <p>Email: john.doe@gmail.com</p>
        </div>

        <div class='vCardBack hidden'>
            <h3 class="leadName">Info on John Doe</h3>
            <p>Sales:</p>
            <ul>
                <li class="tab">Naturals2Go</li>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab">Units Bought: 4</li>
                        <li class="tab"></li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="vCardContainer">
    <div class="vCard">
        <div class='vCardFront'>
            <h3 class="leadName">John Doe</h3>
            <p>Phone: 270-331-0169</p>
            <p>Email: john.doe@gmail.com</p>
        </div>

        <div class='vCardBack hidden'>
            <h3 class="leadName">Info on John Doe</h3>
            <p>Sales:</p>
            <ul>
                <li class="tab">Naturals2Go</li>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab">Units Bought: 4</li>
                        <li class="tab"></li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
jQuery(".vCard").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("flipped");
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using some pretty simple JS. (and refactoring the HTML structure.)

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out. Trying to get the relative positioned parent to be the height of the absolute positioned child can be a little tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Add this on your
.vCard.vCardFront,
.vCard.vCardBack

`overflow-y: scroll;`

Comment: I actually tried it on your fiddle before i posted this,  and it works

Comment: Undestand that the Div doesnt change its physical size it scrolls through all its content, meaning you can scroll up and down on the content the div stays the same physical size

Comment: OK I got the fiddle to work. however, this is not the desired effect, as stated in the original question. I'm trying to get the div to expand to fit it's content. (I've read through several examples, but can't seem to implement it)

Comment: Fix scroll on the fiddle and remove the overflow-y: scroll on the second class

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean? (read my last comment?)

Comment: If the scrollbar works then thats what i thought you wanted, the Div to be able to show all content, i guess i misunderstood your question then,

Comment: No problem. I'm wanting the div to expand to fit it's content.